# Searching for string match and remove the search if everything was found

Tags: c#, string, dictionary, full-text-search

I have a huge list with some items and i need to search if anything i need has been added to the list and if it is to show the result in a text line, and after the search is full or nothing matches, to remove the "Searching..." line.
I have this code so far and the searching doesn't go away if there is a match or nothing was found:

```
Dictionary<string, Line> Smartphones = new Dictionary<string, Line>
        {
            {"Smartphones/Sony", new Line { Text = "Sony Xperia Z5 Premium", Color = () => Settings.Sony }},
            {"Smartphones/iPhone", new Line { Text = "iPhone 6S Plus", Color = () => Settings.iPhone }},
            {"Smartphones/Samsung", new Line { Text = "Galaxy S6 Edge", Color = () => Settings.Samsung }}
        };
        Line alert_me = Smartphones.Where(kv => text.StartsWith(kv.Key, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).Select(kv => kv.Value).FirstOrDefault();
        if (alert_me != null)
        {
            if (alert.Contains(new Line { Text = "Searching...", Color = () => Settings.Smartphones }))
            {
                alert.Remove(new Line { Text = "Searching...", Color = () => Settings.Smartphones });
            }
            alert.Add(alert_me); return;
        }
        if (text.Contains("Samsung"))
        {
            alert.Add(new Line { Text = "Searching...", Color = () => Settings.Smartphones });
        }
```

Is there any other modern/elegant way to do this...i just think the code is to big for a matching search.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to find and remove new instances of a Line object.

```
if (alert.Contains(new Line { Text = "Searching...", Color = () => Settings.Smartphones }))
{
    alert.Remove(new Line { Text = "Searching...", Color = () => Settings.Smartphones });
}
```

As I consider, as long as alert is a HashSet you should use `RemoveWhere()` and lambda inside. 
Like

```
alert.RemoveWhere(x=> x.Text == "Searching...");
```

Comment: Cannot convert lambda expression to type Line because it is not a delegate type...

Comment: @user2558921 Can you show what code are you trying to run?

Comment: @user2558921 For HashSet you should use `RemoveWhere`. I've updated the answer.